# Get Video Thumbnail from specified postion - Android

Tags: java, android, thumbnails

Right now I am creating thumbnail using below method-

```
 Bitmap thumb = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(path,
                    MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND);
```

This method is working fine, The problem is I am getting thumbnail from the beginning of the video (Might be from 00:00 or 00:01).

My Ques is, Can I get Thumbnail from specified position(Let's say 00:05)?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can by below way..

```
MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
try {
   retriever.setDataSource(filePath);
   //here 5 means frame at the 5th sec.
    bitmap = retriever.getFrameAtTime(5);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
   // Assume this is a corrupt video file
}
```

For more info check it [MediaMetadataRetriever](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever.html)

Comment: it requires min API level 10, is there anything available from API 8? Thanks for your answer.

Comment: From android API there is no availability..For this you need to use third party libraries like FFMPEG

Comment: The time-stamp should be in microseconds and not seconds.

Answer (score 1):

[FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever](https://github.com/wseemann/FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever) will accomplish what you want and it works with API 7+:

```
FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever();
try {
    retriever.setDataSource(filePath);
    //here 5 means frame at the 5th sec.
    bitmap = retriever.getFrameAtTime(5);
} catch (Exception ex) {
    // Assume this is a corrupt video file
}
```